# I am using Lyx to edit my document and would like to reduce the spacing between subsections

Tags: spacing, sectioning, lyx

I am using floats throughout the text perhaps this messes with spacing. It seems such an easy thing to adjust, yet I find no answer.

Comment: I've supplied a generic answer to your problem addressing lengths between text elements and headings/floats. You need to provide more detail in order to obtain an adequate solution. For example, what document class are you using? You mention both floats and headings; is this correct? Perhaps you can include an image of the desired and current output to highlight your problem. See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://goo.gl/59Kig)

Answer (score 4):

As a general guide, the [`layouts` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) provides the different lengths associated with various elements within a document.

#### Section layout:

In the default LaTeX document classes (`article`, `book` and `report`), sections are set using `\@startsection`. Here's a take with some description of when each argument means if you wish to change `\subsubsection`, say (taken directly from the `layouts` documentation):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection%
  {subsubsection}% name
  {3}% level
  {0mm}% indent
  {-\baselineskip}% beforeskip
  {0.5\baselineskip}% afterskip
  {\large\itshape}}% style
\makeatother
```

A visual representation of the length locations/usage within the context of the heading (two different types, depending on whether `afterskip` is positive/negative ~ display/run-in):

[image]

There's also the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) packages that could help in adjusting these values.

#### Floats layout:

Lengths affecting the location of textual content with respect to floats are `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep`. Their default values, as set in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), are:

```
\newskip\floatsep
\newskip\textfloatsep
\newskip\intextsep
\setlength\floatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}% 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}% 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\setlength\intextsep   {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}% 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
```

A visual representation of their locationa amongst other document elements are given in Figure 13:

[image]

You can modify this in the preamble of your LyX document. For example, adding

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
```

would fix the separation between top/bottom floats to a line of text.

---

Note that all these modifications, if applied, will have a global effect on your document. This is a good thing, for the sake of consistency. However, manual modifications are also possible (not recommended), and should be left until the end of your document production.